# Failed to create a simulated 2D dynamic array in a structure

Tags: c, pointers

```
struct Level_Info
{
  char **Map;
} Level[Level_Amount];

for (int Cnt_1 = 0; Cnt_1 < Level_Amount; Cnt_1++)
{
  Level[Cnt_1].Map = malloc(Rbn_Col * sizeof(char*));
  for (int Cnt_2 = 0; Cnt_2 < Rbn_Col; Cnt_2++)
    Level[Cnt_1].*(Map+Cnt_2) = malloc(Rbn_Row * sizeof(char)); /* line 10 */
}
```

GCC says: `expected identifier before 「*」 token` at line 10, so how to fix it?

Comment: Snippets without line numbers make it easier for the one wantin to copy/pate your code and feed it to a compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
Level[Cnt_1].*(Map+Cnt_2) = malloc(Rbn_Row * sizeof(char));
```

with

```
*(Level[Cnt_1].Map+Cnt_2) = malloc(Rbn_Row * sizeof(char));
```

or simply with

```
Level[Cnt_1].Map[Cnt_2] = malloc(Rbn_Row * sizeof(char));
```

As `sizeof(char)` by defintion is always 1 you could also do

```
Level[Cnt_1].Map[Cnt_2] = malloc(Rbn_Row);
```

or to stay flexible in terms of what `Map` points to do

```
Level[Cnt_1].Map[Cnt_2] = malloc(Rbn_Row * sizeof(Level[Cnt_1].Map[Cnt_2][0]));
```

---

Additionally please note that the prefered type to index arrays is `size_t`, not `int`.

So your snippet should look like:

```
struct Level_Info
{
  char ** Map;
} Level[Level_Amount];

for (size_t Cnt_1 = 0; Cnt_1 < Level_Amount; ++Cnt_1)
{
  Level[Cnt_1].Map = malloc(Rbn_Col * sizeof(Level[Cnt_1].Map[0]));

  for (size_t Cnt_2 = 0; Cnt_2 < Rbn_Col; ++Cnt_2)
  {
    Level[Cnt_1].Map[Cnt_2] = malloc(Rbn_Row * sizeof(Level[Cnt_1].Map[Cnt_2][0]));
  }
}
```